# Android: onClickListener in the ArrayAdapter not responding

Tags: android

I created an activity, created the list view and set the `setItemsCanForus()` method to true so that each view in the adapter can have its own onclicklisteners. I managed to make the list but now the views don't respond to the clicks.

Here's the part of the activity.

```
private ArrayList<String> filePath;
private ListView lv;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_find_video);

    **filePath = new ArrayList<>();
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.find_video_list);
    fetchVideoList();
    lv.setItemsCanFocus(true);**
}

private void fetchVideoList() {
    String[] projection = {
            MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails._ID
    };
    // Create the cursor pointing to the SDCard
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            projection, // Which columns to return
            null,       // Return all rows
            null,
            MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.VIDEO_ID);

    assert cursor != null;
    cursor.close();

    filePath = getFilePaths();

    VideoFromDeviceItem adapter = new VideoFromDeviceItem(FindVideoActivity.this, filePath);
    **lv.setAdapter(adapter);**
}
```

And here is the class that extends the `ArrayAdapter<String>` class.

```
public class VideoFromDeviceItem extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Activity context;
    private final ArrayList<String> filePaths;

    public VideoFromDeviceItem(Activity context, ArrayList<String> filePaths) {
        super(context, R.layout.video_item, filePaths);
        this.context = context;
        this.filePaths = filePaths;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.upload_list, null, true);

        VideoView videoItem = (VideoView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.videoItem);
        TextView tvFilePath = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvFilePath);
        TextView tvVideoRunningTime = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvVideoRunningTime);

        videoItem.setVideoPath(filePaths.get(position));
        videoItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context, position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        // remove the file path and simply get the file name.
        String fullPath = filePaths.get(position);
        String shortName = new File(fullPath).getName();
        tvFilePath.setText(shortName);

        // get the running time of the video.
        long runningTime = getVideoRunningTime(filePaths.get(position));
        String strRunningTime = fromMillisecToFormattedTime(runningTime);
        tvVideoRunningTime.setText(strRunningTime);

        return rowView;
    }
```

As you can see above, I set an `OnClickListener()` to a video view with a toast message just to test if the listener is actually responding. And there's no response from the clicks.

Comment: Probably crashing because `position ` is `int` which is passed as second parameter in `Toast.makeText` method. try it using `String.valueOf(position)`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Well I already tried again by replacing the `position` variable in the toast with a plain text and fixing the `final int position` to `int position` in the `getView()` method's parameter. Didn't work either.

Comment: Have you added `videoItem . setClickable(true)` for VideoView?

Comment: I tried that as well.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK isn't the `clickable` attribute `true` by default?

Comment: try android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" on the root view of your list row layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try chaning this :

```
private final Activity context;
```

to this :

```
private final Context context;
```

And your constructor to this :

```
public VideoFromDeviceItem(Context context, ArrayList<String> filePaths) {
    super(context, R.layout.video_item, filePaths);
    this.context = context;
    this.filePaths = filePaths;
}
```

### EDIT

You can use this instead :

```
videoItem.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return false;
    }
});
```

> Why the `onTouchListener()` not `onClickListener()` in this case?

There are some bugs with `onClickListener()` since it's a `VideoView`... so the best way to do the `onClickListener()` is the `onTouchListener()` **BUT** if you want the `onClickListener()` just add a `Button` inside of your `VideoView` or wherever and you can set the `setOnClickListener()` on it .

Comment: I don't know for sure. It just don't work as written in the snippet.

Comment: Now it's working! Thanks but why the `onTouchListener()` not `onClickListener()` in this case?

Comment: I see. So I assume that there's still no problem using `onClickListener()` with the other views like `Button`s. Another question - What's makes a difference by calling an `Activity` instance in the adapter class instead of `Context` class?

Comment: @newbieprogrammer I'm used to use `Context`  instead, and thought it was the problem :P

Comment: Okay. Now I found out that it's okay to use Context as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot! you saved my time a lot for this!